# Trying to make a function return me another function which returns a sum of two parameters

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a function with two parameters return me another function with parameters and that functions parameters are replaced with the function i call. Then that function returns me the sum of two parameters.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rbmoyy0j/

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function countApples(janesApples, bobsApples){
return janesApples + bobsApples;
}

function avg(a, b){
return countApples(a, b)/2);
}


document.write(avg(3, 9));

</script>
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Syntax errors aside, no place in your code returns a function — your functions return values. document.write calls avg(3,9) then avg calls countApples(3,9) then countApples adds 3 + 9 and returns 12, then avg divides 12/2 and returns 6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it's OK, you just have a syntax error, a parenthesis that should not be here :

```
return countApples(a, b)/2;
```

*(voting to close as typo)*

Answer (score 0):

Braces in return statement of `avg` function.
It should be:

```
return avg(3,9);
```